# Can I visit other GCC countries if I hold a valid visa for one of them?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, kuwait, gcc

Can Indian citizens visit other [G.C.C countries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooperation_Council_for_the_Arab_States_of_the_Gulf) i.e. UAE, Saudi Arabia, Oman, Bahrain, Qatar on a Kuwait employment visa? What about if I have a tourist visa?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you are almost free to move within GCC countries as long as you are on a permanent visa (work visa) in one of the GCC countries (except Saudi Arabia). Rules are little different from one country to another but in general you will get a temporary visa upon arrival. Bear in mind that not all job titles are allowed. The following links have information for some countries for visa on arrival for GCC residents:

- [Oman](http://www.rop.gov.om/english/dg_pr_visas_agcc.asp): Visas are on arrival and for 4 weeks, can be extended one more week.
- [Bahrain](http://www.evisa.gov.bh/VisaBhr10En.html): Visas are on arrival for 7 days, and can be electronically (online).
- [UAE](http://www.mofa.gov.ae/mofa_english/portal/79e01fed-3501-4ebb-accd-9e27950433a7.aspx): Visas are on arrival for 30 days.
- [Qatar](http://portal.www.gov.qa/wps/portal/services/inviduallandingpages/entry%20visas/gcc%20resident%20visit%20visa/): Visas are on arrival and one month, can be extended another month.
- [Kuwait](http://www.kuwait-airport.com.kw/Public/visa_e.htm): Visas are on arrival for 3 months.

Again, make sure that the job title in your visa matches the one of the allowed job titles.

Comment: Ok. Nice information about that. But only valid for the work permit holders.

Answer (score 5):

Most GCC member states (with the exception of Saudi Arabia) allow permanent residents of GCC countries to get a visa on arrival.

If you are on a visit visa, then you will have to apply separately. There are no GCC-wide visas (like the schengen) or reciprocal policies between countries.

In other words, you need a visa for each country you visit.

To prevent a large influx of unskilled labor traveling across borders, the visa on arrival is restricted to those that hold certain "professional designations".  This is a loose term and the interpretation is left up to each country. Some are more liberal than others.

You should also have at a minimum 6 months residency left and your passport should also not expire within 6 months.

For the more sundry details, have a look at the links in @MeNoTalk's [answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/37885/1375).

Specifically for Kuwait - if you are eligible for visa on arrival (that is, your designation is suitable for such a visa); you cannot drive to the other GCC member state. You have to fly. This is because Saudi Arabia stopped the issuance of transit visas for residents.

The only way to transit through Saudi Arabia (by road), if you are not a GCC citizen is to obtain a visa from the destination country, or hold permanent residency at the destination country.

If you fly, there are no restrictions as Saudi Arabia does not have airside transit visas (like the UK and some other countries).